# Magento, some of my products are not displayed correctly

Tags: magento

This is how products are supposed to be displayed: [correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tey9T.png)

And this is how some of the products are displayed: [incorrect image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccnZE.png)

As you can see on the incorrect image, only the product is displayed, everything else on the site is missing like the menu and footer.

The whole UI is missing on some products, there is no cart and no abillity to add products to the cart.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the backend `Catalog -> Manage products -> Edit -> Design -> Page Layout`
If it is set to `empty` thats why the header and footer is not loaded.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Page Layout is set to "No layout updates" - but that is also what it is set to on the products that display correctly.

Comment: Any console errors? Is this the only product which shows like this?

Comment: No, there are multiple products that shows like this. There are some console errors, but those are also displayed on the correct products.

Comment: Ok, compare the settings of the product which isn't showing correctly with a product which does show correct on the frontend.

Comment: In second picture and header missing? or just screen shot cuted?

Comment: Hi Frank, there are some minor differences but none of relevance unfortunately.

Comment: Arnoldas, the header is missing, and so is the footer. Everything but the actual product is missing, the whole UI is missing so you can't add products to the basket.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also check with that product's category layout update
just goto catalog->manage categories -> custom design

[category layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PalGL.png)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. that doesn't seem to be the solution, they all have the correct layout.